# 3G internet sharing from laptop to Android

Tags: windows-7, android, internet-sharing

I want to have internet connection on my Samsung Galaxy S3 running Android 4.1.1. Right now I have it only on my Windows 7 laptop, which uses a USB 3G modem.

How can I make my phone use internet connection from my laptop? I have a data cable.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to let Windows 7 laptop provide an internet connection to my Android?](http://superuser.com/questions/434628/how-to-let-windows-7-laptop-provide-an-internet-connection-to-my-android), http://superuser.com/questions/407371/how-to-use-pcs-internet-connection-on-android-phone?rq=1

Comment: That's known as "reversed tethering" and we have a tag for that on the Android site: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reverse-tether

Answer (score 0):

If your laptop has Wi-Fi with recent enough drivers, probably the easiest way is to use the [Wireless Hosted Network](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd815243%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) feature provided by Windows 7 to create a software Wi-Fi access point on your laptop, and then use the Internet Connection Sharing feature to allow Wi-Fi clients (your Android device) use the internet connection through that access point. You will not need to install any additional software on your Android device — just set up a Wi-Fi connection.

Windows does not provide any builtin GUI to set up a software Wi-Fi access point (only some `netsh` commands), but you can use third-party software for this:

- [Virtual Wifi Hotspot for Windows 7 & 8](http://virtualwifihotspot.codeplex.com/) (free, open source)
- [Virtual Router - Wifi Hot Spot for Windows 8, Windows 7 and 2008 R2](http://virtualrouter.codeplex.com/)  (free, open source)
- [Connectify](http://www.connectify.me/) (closed source, free version does not allow 3G connection sharing)

If you must use the USB cable connection for any reason, you need to set up **reverse tethering** on your Android device. Unfortunately, this feature is not provided by standard Android, and third-party apps will most likely require a rooted device. A better place to ask about this is the [Android Enthusiasts](https://android.stackexchange.com/) site — search for ”reverse tethering” there (e.g., see [this question](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/2298/11251)).

Comment: Host name could not be found. IP address could not be found. Why ?